# Fitting multiple peaks to a dataset and extracting individual peak information in R

Tags: r, histogram, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a number of datasets composed of counts of features at various elevations. Currently there is data for each 1m interval from 1-30m. When plotted, many of my datasets exhibit 3-4 peaks, which are indicative of height layers.

Here is a sample dataset:

> Height <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
>   Counts <-c(4000,2000,500,300,200,100,0,0,400,700,800,800,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,2200,1700,1100,500,0,0,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,4000,2000)

I would like to fit some manner of curve function to these datasets in order to determine the total number of ‘peaks’, the peak center location (i.e. height) and peak width. 
I could perform this kind of analysis by fitting multiple Gaussian functions manually using the fityk software some time ago, I would however like to know if it is possible to perform such a process automatically through R?

I’ve explored a number of other posts concerning fitting peaks to histograms, such as through the mixtools package, however I do not know if you could extract individual peak information.

Any help you can supply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `diff(Counts)` and `diff(diff(Counts))` should help you identify the peaks. Is peak width a simple definition?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I should have defined peak width better. I am referring to the full width at half maximum (FWHM) of the individual peaks.

Answer (score 4):

"How do I fit a curve to my data" is way too broad of a question, because there are countless ways to do this.  It's also probably more suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ than here.  However, `ksmooth` from base R is a pretty good starting point for a basic smoother:

```
plot(Height,Counts)
smoothCounts<-ksmooth(Height,Counts,kernel="normal",bandwidth=2)
dsmooth<-diff(smoothCounts$y)
locmax<-sign(c(0,dsmooth))>0 & sign(c(dsmooth,0))<0
lines(smoothCounts)
points(smoothCounts$x[locmax],smoothCounts$y[locmax],cex=3,c=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple peak identification could be along the following lines. Looks reasonable?

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
Height = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30),
Counts = c(4000,2000,500,300,200,100,0,0,400,700,800,800,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,2200,1700,1100,500,0,0,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,4000,2000)
)

# crude dHeights/dCounts
dt[,d1 := c(NA,diff(Counts))]
# previous crude dHeights/dCounts (d2Heights/dCounts2 will be even more crude so comparing change in dHeight/dCounts instead)
dt[,d2 := c(tail(d1,-1),NA)]

# local maxima
dtpeaks <- dt[d1 >=0 & d2 <=0]
```

I'm not very sure how you would calculate FWHM for the peaks, if you can explain the process then I should be able to help.

Comment: Once the bell-shaped function, or peak, is fitted to the data, for example a Gaussian. Each peak is then considered a separate entity.

The full width at half maximum (FWHM) can be summarized as: the width of the bell-shaped curve (heights) at the middle value (counts), which is half the maximum value from that at the top of the curve.This can be visualized as http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/FWHM.svg

Comment: Haha, I didn't mean a wiki link, I was asking specifically in this example. So how would you calculate the width for the peak at 29?